# Current User changes after ChangePassword

Tags: asp.net-membership

in Admin panel , admin could add new admin users or manage existing ones .

the problem is when I try to change one of users password using ChangePassword control .after successful change , the logged in user is changed .

eg I log in as "admin1" . I go to UsersPage . I try to change "admin2"'s password . after that the name in Loginstatus control at the top of page that shows current user's name displays "admin2" !

Edit : I even tried it in a an empty project with just asp.net controls without a line of code but still current user changes after change password for any user

Edit : now I use ChangePassword method of membership instead of asp.net control and the problem is solved !

Answer (score 0):

if i am not wrong, here is the anwser. `"admin could add new admin users or manage existing ones ."`

basically he is also a admin(admin 2 user), so when he's editing his password, asp.net membership will check for cookies.as the user(admin 2) has the permission to do changes,so the login control displaying (admin 2 user) name.

1. in behind the scenes, asp.net membership will check for the
   particular user against whether he's in the specified role or not
   (in this case "Admin" role).
2. if the user exist, in the role, then it will allow to do changes

Comment: the smae problem happens when Admin tries to change passowrd for a normal user that hasn't "admin" role . I mean after changing password , current user changes and beacause new user doesn't have admin role user will be redirected to login page . I can't Understand . Confused...